# Add project from Github to Dev Story yields “invalid github username”

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I am trying to add a project from my Github but I have an error:

[image]

My username is valid. What I am doing wrong?

---

This issue is reproducible.

#### Steps

1. Go to developer story
2. Choose open source
3. Choose import from github in the bottom

You can see this issue there.

Comment: those who voted to close, please retract the close vote. This is not off topic

Comment: How in the world a bug about a product of SE is off topic from meta?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for reporting this!

This was definitely a mistake on our part. We didn't have proper checks in place, so you were seeing an incorrect error message for what was really a rate limit exceeded exception. This has now been fixed!